# Can't pass my Javascript variable to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

i've a problem with passing my Javascript variable to PHP using AJAX. My `$remove` can't echo out when clicking the button.

HTML Code:

```
<p><button class="btn-remove">Remove</button></p>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove');

removeBtn.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const toBeRemovedName = item.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML;

    $.ajax({
        url: "./shopping_cart.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {toBeRemovedName: toBeRemovedName},
    });
    })
})
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['toBeRemovedName'])) {
    $remove = $_POST['toBeRemovedName'];
    echo $remove;
}
```

Comment: You are sending HTML code to the php function, which will cause alot of errors, you need to specify the id to be removed

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Ajax is to make an HTTP request with JS and **handle the response with JS**.

You aren't doing anything to look at the data that is echoed.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://postman-echo.com/post",
  method: "post",
  data: {
    example: 12345
  }
}).then(response => console.log(response));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to navigate to a new page, then submit a `<form>`. Don't use Ajax.

Comment: Can you use jQuery's ajax function like this? I've always understood you need functions like, `beforeSend` `success` inside your ajax options json

Comment: @JoshBonnick — Yes. That's why the live demo in the answer works.

Answer (score -1):

Why not make a normal AJAX request with javascript instead and then you'd use the variable you are trying to pass as a query parameter instead. For example,

```js
const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove');

removeBtn.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const toBeRemovedName = item.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML;

    $.ajax({
        url: "./shopping_cart.php?toBeRemovedName=" + toBeRemovedName,
        method: "GET"
    });
  })
})
```

Then your php code will look like this.

```php
if(isset($_GET['toBeRemovedName'])) {
    $remove = $_GET['toBeRemovedName'];
    echo $remove;
}
```

Comment: `method: "POST"` and you have GET requests. Don't think that'll work.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question, he's trying to ascertain how he can get access to the echoed value inside his php

Comment: But then again, this is still not the best practise. Think of it as a tweak to help you achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Changed that to get @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Right on Stephen :) P.s.: Not my downvote. Actually, I upvoted it.

Comment: When i hit the button i obtain a specific name, which i need to obtain with Javascript. Afterwards i've a PHP  array (in which i send the javascript with AJAX to) array which contains several names. I need to check if this specific name is inside the php array and if it is, remove that name from the array.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that you also have to treat or handle the response you get from the AJAX request you made. @DarkFelcore

Comment: @stephenwonder Why do i need to work with the response if i only need to send it to php? I don't need to send it back to JS

Comment: Then the code snippet should work just fine for you. Make a GET request to the ENDPOINT you are looking at using query params and get the value in your php code using the $_GET superglobal. @DarkFelcore.

Comment: @stephenwonder Can i post the changes above and could you take a look again please? It doesn't work yet..

Comment: Sure why not @DarkFelcore

Comment: @stephenwonder I reposted my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525791/using-in-array-to-compare-array-data-doesnt-work