# Using in_array to compare array data doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

As you can see in the picture, several products. Each product div has a `remove` button. When I hit this button, the product name of that specific product is stored into a `toBeRemoved` JS variable. I need to send this variable to PHP. To realize this I used Ajax Get Method in which I pass the variable through the URL:

[image: IMG]

HTML CODE:

```
<p><button class="btn-remove">Remove</button></p>
```

Javascript Code:

```
const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove');

removeBtn.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const toBeRemovedName = item.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML;

        $.ajax({
            url: "./shopping_cart.php?toBeRemovedName=" + toBeRemovedName,
            method: "GET"
        });
    });
});
```

My PHP script already contains an array with all the product names you can see on the picture (`$_SESSION['name_arr']`). What I would like to do is: compare the variable `toBeRemovedName` with all the array elements. If true --> remove that name from the array. The problem: it seems that the `$remove` variable doesn't get the information passed in Javascript? I already got some code sample:

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //contains all the product names that you can see on the picture
    $name_arr = $_SESSION['name_arr'];   


    if(isset($_GET['toBeRemovedName'])) {
        $remove = $_GET['toBeRemovedName'];
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($name_arr); $i++) {
            if(in_array($remove, $name_arr)) {
                array_splice($name_arr, $i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump` `$name_arr` and `$remove`

Comment: var_dump($arr_name) --> array(2) { [0]=> string(38) "Tommy Hilfiger - White RN 0562 T-Shirt" [1]=> string(29) "Tommy Jeans - Black Pull 9105" }  AND var_dump($remove) --> NULL

Comment: So what is actually sent in the url? Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. (F12)

Comment: @charlietfl If i hit for example the first remove button, a GET request is send in the network tab. If i open the html response the first product is removed (like i want) but on my page nothing happen can't see the get request either in the URL

Comment: Your get variable is empty, check that your javascript is actually sending it by console logging it or using network tab

Comment: @JoshBonnick please look my answer above. I explain it

Comment: @JoshBonnick also get a 302 error when clickiong on the button

Comment: Also will need to update the session variable when you do change it. Not at all clear what you expect from all of this. You don't send any response from php and you don't handle any ajax response either

Comment: @charlietfl I will try to find it on my own.. it's difficult to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a bug in your Js code.

Replace your Js code with this instead and try again.

```js
let removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove');
removeBtn = [...removeBtn];

removeBtn.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const toBeRemovedName = item.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML;

        $.ajax({
            url: "./shopping_cart.php?toBeRemovedName=" + toBeRemovedName,
            method: "GET"
        });
    });
});
```

Why not hide the element with JavaScript instead after an HTTP status code of 200. Furthermore, If the element has been removed as you mentioned in one of your comments, hiding it with JavaScript will be a better option and you get a good user experience too. Nobody really likes page reload these days. If you want a reload, you can do that with javascript using the code below.

```js
 window.location.reload()
```

That'd give you a window reload as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does the second line mean?

Comment: The second line(Javascript Code) in the comment would refresh the current browser window.